# python - trying to override __getattr__ for dynamically added class but only sort of works

Tags: python, class, dynamic, getattr

I am trying to add a new class to an existing class at run 
time (using "type(...)").  I am also trying to override that 
new class' __getattr__ so that I can do my own behavior on 
attributes that are not in the new class.  For example, 
I have class foo, I add class "tool" and I want foo.tool.test 
to do something of my own.  The code below works but only partly. If I explicitly call __getattr__, it works (see first print) 
but when I reference foo.tool.test, my overridden __getattr__  does not get called and an attrbute error is raised.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.NameList=[]
        # add new class to ourself
        self.tool = type('tool', (object,), {} )
        # override new class' __getattr__ with call to ourself
        setattr(self.tool, "__getattr__", self.__getattr__ )
        # add one well known test name for now
        self.NameList.append( "test" )

    # should be called by our newly added "tool" object but is only called sometimes...
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # print( "__getattr__: %s" % attr )
        if( attr in self.NameList ):     
            return( 99 )
        raise AttributeError("--%r object has no attribute %r" % (type(self).__name__, attr))       

foo = Foo()
# access tool class attribute "test" - it should be seen by the override __getattr__
# the following works...
print( "foo.tool.__getattr__=%d" % foo.tool.__getattr__("test") )  
# but the following does not - why is this not the same as the line above???
print( "foo.tool.test=%d" % foo.tool.test )
```

Comment: You refer to `tool` as a class, but also as the `object`. The `__getattr__` will work ok on an instance of `tool`. eg `foo.tool().test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python looks for special methods like `__getattr__` in an instance's bases
`__dict__`s, not in the instance's `__dict__`.

`self.tool` is a class. `self.tool.test`, therefore, will call the  `__getattr__` of `self.tool`'s class (which is `object`) -- this is not what we want to happen.

Instead, make `self.tool` an instance, whose class has a `__getattr__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.NameList=[]
        # add new class to ourself
        toolcls = type('tool', (object,), { '__getattr__' : self.__getattr__, } )
        self.tool = toolcls()
        self.NameList.append( "test" )

    # should be called by our newly added "tool" object but is only called sometimes...
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # print("__getattr__: (%s, %s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr) )
        if( attr in self.NameList ):     
            return( 99 )
        raise AttributeError("--%r object has no attribute %r" % (
            type(self).__name__, attr)) 

foo = Foo()
print( "foo.tool.__getattr__=%d" % foo.tool.__getattr__("test") )
print( "foo.tool.test=%d" % foo.tool.test )
```

yields

```
foo.tool.__getattr__=99
foo.tool.test=99
```

Also, beware that the above code can lead to infinite recursion if an instance of `Foo` is made without `self.NameList` being defined. See [Ned Batchelder's post on this suprising pitfall](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html).

To protect against the possibility of infinite recursion here, use

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    # print("__getattr__: (%s, %s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr) )
    if attr == 'NameList':
        raise AttributeError()
    if( attr in self.NameList ):     
        return( 99 )
    raise AttributeError("--%r object has no attribute %r" % (
        type(self).__name__, attr))
```

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the explanation. I need to read it a few more times to grok it.  I also got it to work by defining a class outside Foo but the end result is the same as your - yours is much more succinct and compact and self-contained.

Comment: Opps, hit return too early.  Why does py use the base's __dict__[__getattr__] and not the instance's?  And, related, why is your instantiation of toolcls that adds the __getattr__ functionally different than mine where I did the "setattr(self.tool...)

Comment: @staggart: I wish I could find a link to documentation which explains this, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find it. That special methods are looked for in the class rather than the instance is true for `new-style` classes, not classic classes. With classic classes, you could put an `__add__` method in an instance's `__dict__` to get special behavior for `x + y`, but not so with new-style classes. Now you must put `__add__` in the classes's `__dict__`.

Comment: @staggart: `setattr(self.tool, '__getattr__', ...)` puts `__getattr__` in `self.tool.__dict__`. Using `toolcls = type('tool', ..., {'__getattr__':...})` puts `__getattr__` in `toolscls.__dict__`. We could have written `setattr(toolscls, '__getattr__', ...)` just as well. But since the 3rd argument to type allows us to add stuff to `toolscls.__dict__`, we might as well use it. The key ingredient -- the only really necessary change I made to your code -- was to add the parentheses `()` which makes `self.tool` an **instance** of the class.

Comment: \@unutbu: it's clear I do not have a full grasp of the difference between a class and an instance in py.  I think you are saying that in my version I was creating a class, not and instance of a class when I did ... = type(...).  In your case, you created a class first, then instantiated an instance.  In c++ land, it's 100% clear to me but in py, it's not entirely clear to me how a py class behaves.  I need to chew on the subtleties therein.  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @staggart: Yes! Your summary is correct. If there's anything else that needs clarification, just ask.